# How to never show Yellow Error Page?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

For security reasons (not to show .net framework version), I want to be sure that the asp.net yellow page (error page) is never displayed to a visitor.
What is the best practice?
Note that i used Custom as error mode for the httperrors but then:
- Do I have to declare all potential http errors? I could forget a status...
- Better way?

Sample of my web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404Page.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <!-- ETC error for each status .... -->
</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what i have in my web.config for a project. It catches pretty much everything... You can have as many custom error codes as you want using this method.

```
             <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="pgError.aspx">
                <error statusCode="504" redirect="pgNoConnection.aspx"/>
             </customErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that specifying a `defaultRedirect` would cause any error code to be redirected to this default page.

On this example all http error codes are redirected to `GenericError.htm` except for 500, that is redirected to `InternalError.htm`. You can remove the line that cause a different redirection to status code 500 and all error would go to the same page.

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                      mode="RemoteOnly">
          <error statusCode="500"
                 redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
        </customErrors>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) you have the complete MSDN reference for customErrors section

Answer (score 2):

For not getting yellow page follow this steps copied from this [Microsoft article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs):

(1) Design you custom Error page e.g Error.aspx

(2) With the error page completed, configure the web application to use the custom error page in lieu of the Runtime Error YSOD. This is accomplished by specifying the URL of the error page in the  section's defaultRedirect attribute. Add the following markup to your application's Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                      defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

        ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

(3) By default, all types of errors cause the same custom error page to be displayed. However, you can specify a different custom error page for a specific HTTP status code using  children elements within the  section. For example, to have a different error page displayed in the event of a page not found error, which has an HTTP status code of 404, update the  section to include the following markup:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```